# Undefined symbol - confused

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, linker-errors

On Ubuntu 10.04 LTS:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -> g++-4.4
/usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.4
```

I am writing a libssl_ext library in Ubuntu which is based on openssl library (libssl.a and libssl.so)
When I type

```
$nm -C -defined-only -g libssl_ext.so
```

I can see the following symbols defined

```
00005140 D SSLv3_enc_data_Ext
**00002800 T SSLv3_server_method_Ext**
00005174 A __bss_start
00005174 A _edata
0000517c A _end
00003aa8 T _fini
00001954 T _init
00002d70 T ssl3_accept_Ext
00002480 T ssl3_enc_Ext
00002850 T ssl3_get_client_key_exchange_Ext
000026f0 T ssl3_write_Ext
00002320 T ssl3_write_bytes_Ext
```

When I type:

```
$nm -C -defined-only -g libssl.so
```

I can see the following symbols defined

```
....
00018930 T SSLv3_client_method
00050600 D SSLv3_enc_data
00013640 T SSLv3_method
**00013690 T SSLv3_server_method**
00026f40 T TLSv1_client_method
000506c0 D TLSv1_enc_data
00026ea0 T TLSv1_method
00026ef0 T TLSv1_server_method
.....
```

When I call the SSLv3_server_method_Ext in my server.cpp code, it has an issue:

```
server.cpp:70: undefined reference to SSLv3_server_method_Ext()
```

When I type :

```
$ nm -C --undefined-only -g server.o
```

It shows the following:

```
U CRYPTO_free
U ERR_print_errors_fp
U SSL_CIPHER_get_name
U SSL_CTX_ctrl
U SSL_CTX_free
U SSL_CTX_new
U SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list
U SSL_accept
U SSL_free
U SSL_get_current_cipher
U SSL_get_error
U SSL_get_peer_certificate
U SSL_get_version
U SSL_library_init
U SSL_new
U SSL_read
U SSL_set_fd
U SSL_shutdown
U SSL_write
**U SSLv3_server_method**
U X509_NAME_oneline
U X509_free
**U SSLv3_server_method_Ext()**
U __gxx_personality_v0
U accept
U bind
U close
U exit
U htons
U inet_ntoa
U listen
U memset
U perror
U printf
U puts
U socket
U stderr
```

There is a difference when I link the **SSLv3_server_method from libssl.so
with server.o**, it shows as  "U SSLv3_server_method" and can be linked successfully with libssl.so.
But when I link the **SSLv3_server_method_Ext from libssl_ext.so with server.o**, it shows as "U SSLv3_server_method_Ext()"
and failed with undefined reference to SSLv3_server_method_Ext()

Please if someone explains to me **why the server.o is looking for SSLv3_server_method_Ext() instead of SSLv3_server_method_Ext** and how to fix this problem? The linker was correctly looking for SSLv3_server_method when I call libssl.so and it is found.

Comment: You probably need to show your linking command line.  Are you linking with `-lssl_ext` (probably listed before `-lssl`)?  Are you listing the libraries after the object files?

Comment: How are you trying to compile this?

Comment: How are you creating the libraries? My guess: You are making `libssl` link to `libssl_ext` when you build `libssl`.

Comment: Maybe the header needs to be `extern "C"`? (That would count as a bug in openssl if it was in their headers, I think)

Comment: Server.cpp needs to have extern "C" to include the "openssl/ssl_ext.h" header. Then it links successfully. Thank You to your suggestion!